# How to write IN clause query to replace null for no value parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query in which where clause have IN clause and there are large number of values in this IN clause , I want to fetch the result such that if there is no value exist in table for value given in IN clause then a raw containing 0 or null should return for that value. for example..

```
select age,sex,date_joining from emp where name IN ('amit','john','paul','dilip')
```

Now assume for this query ,data for john and paul does not exist in database then result should be like below..

```
21    male   21-AUG-2011
null  null   null
null  null   null
25    male   9-aug-2010
```

we can also have 0 instead of null if null is not possible

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  filter.name
,       emp.age
,       emp.sex
,       emp.date_joining 
from    (
        values ('amit'), ('john'), ('paul'), ('dilip')
        ) filter(name)
left join    
        emp
on      emp.name = filter.name
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c009/1/0)

For older values of SQL Server, replace the line with `values` by:

```
from    (
                  select 'amit'
        union all select 'john'
        union all select 'paul'
        union all select 'dilip'
        ) filter(name)
```

Comment: hi Andomar, I don't know at my system why this give following error
'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'.'

Comment: Might be an old version of SQL Server, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use common table expression to get this result:

```
;With AllEmpDetails as
(
Select [Name] from emp
UNION Select 'amit' 
UNION Select 'john' 
UNION Select 'paul' 
UNION Select 'dilip'
)Select AllEmpDetails.Name, e2.Age, e2.Sex, e2.date_joining 
from AllEmpDetails 
Left Join emp e2 on e2.[Name] = AllEmpDetails.Name
```

In my database, I have already added details for *amit* and *dilip* so i have used `UNION` since you can easily get the detail about the available employees. On the other hand you can use `UNION ALL` with `Distinct`.